# git: removing "a/" from the diff output

Tags: git

The output of `git diff` usually looks like this:

```
diff --git a/tests/test_utils.py b/tests/test_utils.py
index 002d62aaf9..c28b23b0ed 100644
--- a/tests/test_utils.py
+++ b/tests/test_utils.py
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+import os
 from datetime import datetime
```

Now I would like to copy+paste the path. In this case **`tests/test_utils.py`**

But unfortunately there is the prefix **a/** before the path.

If I double click on the path the prefix gets included.

Copy+Paste of the path would be easier if there would be no prefix.

Is there a way to configure git to not output this prefix?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question. The duplicate answers all your questions and more.

Comment: @CodeCaster I searched before asking. May I missed the right terms. Thank you for pointing me to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[diff.noprefix](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffnoprefix)

If it's set, source and destination prefixes are not printed.

```
git config diff.noprefix yes
```

`yes` could be `1` or `true`, case insensitive.